# Object detection in TensorFlow Lite C++ with the MobileNet-SSD v1 model

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

According to this information [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/15633), TensorFlow Lite now supports object detection using the MobileNet-SSD v1 model. There is an example for Java in this [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/examples/android/src/org/tensorflow/demo/TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel.java), but how can the output be parsed in C++? I cannot find any documentation about this. This code shows an example.

```
.......
(fill inputs)
.......

intepreter->Invoke();
const std::vector<int>& results = interpreter->outputs();
TfLiteTensor* outputLocations = interpreter->tensor(results[0]);
TfLiteTensor* outputClasses   = interpreter->tensor(results[1]);
float *data = tflite::GetTensorData<float>(outputClasses);
for(int i=0;i<NUM_RESULTS;i++)
{
   for(int j=1;j<NUM_CLASSES;j++)
   {
      float score = expit(data[i*NUM_CLASSES+j]); // ¿? This does not seem to be correct.
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try implementing expit? expit is not a builtin function... i.e. look at the definition https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.special.expit.html.  You can just do that explicitly as  1/(1+exp(-x)).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to compute expit, you need to define a function to do that. Add at the top:

```
#include <cmath>
```

and then

```
intepreter->Invoke();
const std::vector<int>& results = interpreter->outputs();
TfLiteTensor* outputLocations = interpreter->tensor(results[0]);
TfLiteTensor* outputClasses   = interpreter->tensor(results[1]);
float *data = tflite::GetTensorData<float>(outputClasses);
for(int i=0;i<NUM_RESULTS;i++)
{
   for(int j=1;j<NUM_CLASSES;j++)
   {
      auto expit = [](float x) {return 1.f/(1.f + std::exp(-x));};
      float score = expit(data[i*NUM_CLASSES+j]); // ¿? This does not seem to be correct.
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi aselle, Yes, I computed expit. The source code to get score is indeed correct. I got confused because I was expecting, from Tensorflow Lite, the same results that those given by Tensorflow. The issue seems to be that TensorFlow Lite for object detection in some case generates too much noise, whereas in others it loses good detections, this was discussed here, https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/15633#issuecomment-390290527. So, right know I am still using Tensorflow even for mobile devices. Is this the expected behavior since Tensorflow Lite omits some postprocess nodes?